# What is the correct way to annotate a class with a foreign id using Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, annotations

I am working on converting an existing project over to use Hibernate. I have a class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "user_id")
   private Long userId;

   @Column(name = "group_id_user")
   private Long groupId;

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;

   ...
   // getters and setters....   
}
```

and a class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group")
public class Group {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "group_id")
   private Long groupId;

   @Column(name="group_name")
   private String groupName;

   ...
   // getters and setters....   
}
```

The column named `"group_id_user"` in the `user` table is supposed to be a foreign key to the column named `"group_id"` in the `group` table.

**Is it okay or "correct" to have the classes structured as shown above or should they be structured as shown below to make sure that the foreign key exists in the Database?**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "user_id")
   private Long userId;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "group_id_user")
   private Group group;

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;

   ...
   // getters and setters....   
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group")
public class Group {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "group_id")
   private Long groupId;

   @Column(name="group_name")
   private String groupName;

   ...
   // getters and setters....   
}
```

I have tried using both formats but have had issues both ways. When I use the first format I have issues with the HQL syntax for joins while creating queries. When I try the second format I have issues with fetching just a `User` from the database without a `Group`, or adding a new `User` from a json object the has a `groupId` instead of a `Group` object. So before I spend anymore time switching back and forth between the two formats I want to know for sure **which way should I be using the annotations to best fit industry standard?**

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this if you could change the name of the columns too:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) //This means you will need the database to generate the ids, if you are using Oracle this won't work. You would need to use SEQUENCE.
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "group_id") //There will be no need to specify the join column if you use group_id.
   private Group group;

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;

   ...
   // getters and setters....   
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @Column(name="group_name")
   private String groupName;

   ...
   // getters and setters....   
}
```

Also if you can I would change the name of the tables to plural.

Also I use something that helps me a lot. I have a super class called "Identifiable" which just has the id and it looks like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Identifiable implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9027542469937539859L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Identifiable other = (Identifiable) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

With that you can extend all your classes with ids easily like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends Identifiable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = -90275424699375956859L;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "group_id") //There will be no need to specify the join column if you use group_id.
   private Group group;

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;

   ...
   // getters and setters....   
}
```

However if you cannot change the names, let us know the issues you are having with the traces that are throwing and we might be able to help.

Thanks!